# OpenGL colouring in a shape

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm recreating the old game "Chuckie egg" for a university project, I've drawn the character fine using the below code, but I'm unsure of what type to use in glBegin(?) to colour the object in.

I've tried, GL_QUADS, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and GL_QUAD_STRIP but the only one that works without displaying incorrectly is GL_LINE_LOOP, but this, of course, does not colour the whole shape in.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
void drawMan(void){

//main body outline
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

//set our colour
glColor3ub(255, 255, 0); // yellow

glVertex2f(-0.25f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, 0.875f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.875f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.75f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.75f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.625f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.625f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.375f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.375f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.25f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, 0.25f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, 0.125f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.125f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0.75f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0.75f, -0.5f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.625f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, -0.625f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, -0.75f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, -0.75f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, -0.875f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, -0.875f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, -1.0f);
glVertex2f(-0.25f, -1.0f);
glVertex2f(-0.25f, -0.625f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.625f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex2f(-0.75f, -0.5f);
glVertex2f(-0.75f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.125f);
glVertex2f(-0.25f, 0.125f);
glVertex2f(-0.25f, 0.375f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.375f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.625f);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0.625f);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0.75f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.75f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.85f);
glVertex2f(-0.25f, 0.85f);
//glVertex2f(-0.25f, 1.0f);

glEnd();

//eyes
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glColor3ub(0, 0, 0); // black

glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.625f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, 0.625f);
glVertex2f(0.25f, 0.5f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);

glEnd();


//arm

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glColor3ub(0, 0, 0); // black

glVertex2f(-0.25f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0.0f, -0.5f);
glVertex2f(-0.25f, -0.5f);

glEnd();}
```

Comment: Please don't use the Immediate Mode. It's bad practice. You basically hardcoded your geometry as a list of function calls? Why not do the sane thing and put your geometry data into a buffer and pass OpenGL a pointer to that one?

Comment: @datenwolf im not quite sure what you mean, but I think you mean make a vertex array instead? if so, i will be for other geometry, but this being a uni assignment, i have to demonstrate all of the methods covered so far (draw each bit in a different way).

Comment: @Makka: Technically if you were to use modern OpenGL you could not use Immediate Mode at all. Use of immediate mode has been discouraged for well over 15 years now, and when OpenGL-2 was in discussion 10 years ago a first move to deprecate immediate mode was attempted. Personally I consider immediate mode being as not available at all. If your teachers insist on it, ask them, why you should learn an outdated technique nobody uses in a serious software product for over 15 years now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just draw a random outline and colour it in. You would have to correctly triangulate your shape.

Really this is a job for either a drawing package which can output reasonable geometry, or using a texture instead.

Comment: i think i understand you, for instance, if quads are used you cant just outline the shape you have to have internal vertices breaking the shape down into quad sections? e.g. the letter T (sorry wont format :( )

[][][]
  []
  []

Comment: Correct. You have to make the quads yourself.